# What is the area bounded in the graph?

Tags: linear-algebra, coordinate-systems

I was given a question which I think was incomplete.I want your opinion-

> Find the area of the figure bounded by $x-3=0,y-5=0,x+3=0,y+5=0$.

My attempt-
$x=3,x=-3,y=5,y=-5$ represent parallel lines on the graph.I drew the parallel lines and found out the intersection points of the parallel lines.As a result I get a rectangle and thus found out the area.

Now,my confusion is that one may interpret this as plotting the points $(3,0),(-3,0),(0,5),(0,-5)$ and joining them and finding the area of the figure so formed.

So,which is correct?

Comment: The first interpretation is I think the only reasonable one.

Comment: @AndréNicolas-Do you refer to **....my attempt**??

Comment: The area will be of the curve where two parallel lines to y-axis meet two parallel lines of x-axis so nedd of confusion . We just need three intersection point and area of rectangle is obtained by finding distance of two adjacent sides by distance formula.

Comment: Yes, your first description, the rectangle with sides parallel to the axes.

Comment: @AndréNicolas-Got it in my exam today....did it correct....

Comment: Good. I have seen quite a few cases where a question on a test can be interpreted in more than one way. This was not such a case, the area is $60$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas-Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement

> ...one may interpret this as plotting the points $(3,0),(-3,0),(0,5),(0,-5)$ and joining them...

is wrong.

The points are the intersections of the given lines, so they are: $(3,5),(-3,5), (-3,-5), (3,-5)$.

Comment: So you say that **.....my attempt** line is correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!I got it today in my exam...did it correct....

Answer (score 1):

If you're not under the assumption that the equations represent the $XY$ coordinates, the only valid interpretation is the one you provided.